# Jump-points in pandas dataframe: the moment when the value in a column gets changed

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to identify the jump-points for the following Pandas dataframe.

```
# import Pandas library
import pandas as pd

label1 = ['422','422','422','428','428','453','453','453','453','453','421','421','421','421','421']
label2 = ['13:08','13:08','13:09','13:12','13:12','13:16','13:16','13:17','13:17','13:18','13:20','13:20','13:20','13:20','13:22']

d = {'Id':label1,'Time':label2}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I would like to find the time instant when the value of Id changes. For instance, in the above dataframe, I need the time as 13:09 it is when id 422 becomes 428, and 13:12 when Id 428 becoems 453, and 13:18 when Id 453 becomes 421.

I would appreciate your help in this regard.
[see attached image showing dataframe here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdeUS.png)

Comment: Waht is expected output?

Comment: A dataframe with only the the jump-points and associated labels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution if `Id` is numeric:

First get difference by [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html), replace first or last `NaN` to `0` and comapre for not equal - [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html), last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = df.loc[df['Id'].diff().fillna(0).ne(0), 'Id']
print (s)
3     428
5     453
10    421
Name: Id, dtype: int64

df1 = df[df['Id'].diff(-1).fillna(0).ne(0)].copy()
df1['Id'] = df1['Id'].astype(str) + '-' + s.values.astype(str)
print (df1)
        Id   Time
2  422-428  13:09
4  428-453  13:12
9  453-421  13:18
```

Another more general solution is compare by [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html)ed values and repalce `NaN` by first or last value of column `Id`:

```
df1 = df[df['Id'].ne(df['Id'].shift(-1).fillna(df['Id'].values[-1]))]
print (df1)
    Id   Time
2  422  13:09
4  428  13:12
9  453  13:18
```

And with joined `Id`:

```
s = df.loc[df['Id'].ne(df['Id'].shift().fillna(df['Id'].values[0])), 'Id']
print (s)
3     428
5     453
10    421
Name: Id, dtype: int64

df1 = df[df['Id'].ne(df['Id'].shift(-1).fillna(df['Id'].values[-1]))].copy()
df1['Id'] = df1['Id'].astype(str) + '-' + s.values.astype(str)
print (df1)
        Id   Time
2  422-428  13:09
4  428-453  13:12
9  453-421  13:18
```

Comment: Will it also work if the values in label1 are string instead of numbers?

Comment: No, so new solution was added.